# Excel Interop Chart Hide Chart Area Text

Tags: .net, vb.net, excel, interop, excel-interop

I have created the following chart object using below code( VB.Net and Microsoft Excel Interop)

```vb
Dim ColumnChart As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Chart
Dim ColumnChartShape As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Shape = oSheet.Shapes.AddChart()

ColumnChart = ColumnChartShape.Chart
CCLastRow = oSheet.Rows.End(Excel.XlDirection.xlDown)
CCLR = oSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
CCLC = oSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell).Column
oSheet.Range("$C$3:" & GetExcelColumn(CCLC) & CCLastRow.Row).NumberFormat = "$#,##0_);($#,##0)"
ColumnChartSourceRange = oSheet.Range("$B$3:" & GetExcelColumn(CCLC) & CCLastRow.Row)

With ColumnChart
    .ChartWizard(Source:=ColumnChartSourceRange, Title:="Purchases - " + TextPeriod1Name + " vs " + TextPeriod2Name, PlotBy:=Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlRowCol.xlColumns)
    .ApplyLayout(9, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlChartType.xlColumnClustered)
    .ChartStyle = 34
    .ApplyDataLabels(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlDataLabelsType.xlDataLabelsShowLabel, False, False, False, False, False, True)
    .SeriesCollection(1).DataLabels.Position = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlDataLabelPosition.xlLabelPositionOutsideEnd
    .SeriesCollection(1).Interior.Color = RGB(132, 175, 104)
    .SeriesCollection(2).DataLabels.Position = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlDataLabelPosition.xlLabelPositionOutsideEnd
    .SeriesCollection(2).Interior.Color = RGB(19, 46, 66)
    .PlotArea.Border.Weight = 1
    .PlotArea.Border.Weight = 1
    .PlotArea.Border.Color = ColorTranslator.ToOle(Color.Gray)
    .ChartArea.Width = 563.04
    .ChartArea.Height = 311.76
    .ChartArea.Border.Weight = 1
    .ChartArea.Border.LineStyle = 0
    .Axes(Excel.XlAxisType.xlCategory, Excel.XlAxisGroup.xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
    .Axes(Excel.XlAxisType.xlCategory, Excel.XlAxisGroup.xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = ""
    .Axes(Excel.XlAxisType.xlValue, Excel.XlAxisGroup.xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
    .Axes(Excel.XlAxisType.xlValue, Excel.XlAxisGroup.xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = ""
    .Axes(Excel.XlAxisType.xlValue, Excel.XlAxisGroup.xlPrimary).TickLabels.NumberFormat = "$#,##0"
    .Axes(Excel.XlAxisType.xlValue).MinimumScaleIsAuto = False
    .Axes(Excel.XlAxisType.xlValue).MinimumScale = 0
    .ChartArea.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Size = 12
    .Legend.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Size = 12
    .ChartArea.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Bold = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue
    .Legend.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Bold = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue
```

I am trying to hide the text marked in oval but I am not able to. Please let me know the setting to hide that text. I have tried to set Axix Text to empty, but not working.
[image]

Comment: Not sure if it helps, but I have always started with an existing Excel file with all the charts and formatting set up manually, in Excel, before doing any automation. Then you just fill in the data with .Net. Just my 2 cents.

Comment: Thanks. I am doing the same .Figured out that I have to delete the Axes. But not sure hot to.

Comment: Could able to achieve this by adding the following line..Axes(Excel.XlAxisType.xlCategory, Excel.XlAxisGroup.xlPrimary).Delete()

Answer (score 0):

Just change this piece :

```vb
.Axes(Excel.XlAxisType.xlCategory, Excel.XlAxisGroup.xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
```

to

```vb
.Axes(Excel.XlAxisType.xlCategory, Excel.XlAxisGroup.xlPrimary).HasTitle = False
```